# missing labels with ndimage.label

Tags: python, python-3.x, image-processing, connected-components

I am trying to isolate part of an image using connected component labeling.
I am using scipy's ndimage.label on this image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a6DhM.png)

for some reason the result is this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/naS3f.png)

The part of the image that actually interests me is the white triangle in the upper right corner, which for some reason is labelled as background.
What am I doing wrong?

The code I'm using is:

```
import numpy as np 
from scipy import misc
from scipy import ndimage
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.filters import threshold_otsu
from skimage.measure import label
from skimage.morphology import closing, square
from skimage.color import label2rgb
from scipy.ndimage.measurements import label

im = misc.imread('20588046_024ee3569b2605dc_MG_R_ML_ANON.jpg')
med_im = ndimage.median_filter(im1, 3)
bw = closing(med_im > 170, square(3))
fill_bw = ndimage.binary_fill_holes(bw)
s = [[1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1]]
label_im, nb_labels = ndimage.label(fill_bw, structure=s)
sizes = ndimage.sum(fill_bw, label_im, range(nb_labels + 1))
mask_size = sizes < 1000
remove_pixel = mask_size[label_im]
label_im[remove_pixel] = 0

plt.imshow(label_im, cmap=plt.cm.spectral)
plt.show()
```

I've also tried using it without the structure, and I'm getting the same result.
I am new to python so I apologiza if the code is a little messy

Comment: Can you post a block of code that shows what you're doing? This problem may be data-specific, but it would help diagnose what's happening if we have a bit more context.

Comment: Answering "What am I doing wrong?" without seeing what you're doing is like playing the lottery. Maybe we get lucky and guess right, but it's highly unlikely.

Comment: You're right. Don't know why I thought I would get any help without posting the code itself.